# How do you retrieve the contents of another cell if the the sister column of the range includes the exact variant?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a sheet with the following cell contents:

Sheet1

1. A2: "how to choose between right and wrong"
2. A3: "what is the best baseball bat"

What I am trying to do is come up with a formula that reviews the range of another sheet (Sheet2!A2:B) and provides the first match result in column B of the same row (see screenshot).

Example:
List item 1 (above) should show up for "Prepositional" and List item 2 (above) should show up for "Informational"

However, because the word bat has "at" in it the Intent column it chooses is "Prepositional"

Here is the formula I have thus far

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A,A2)),0))
```

How do you retrieve the contents of another cell if the the sister column of the range includes the exact variant?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\w+"), D:E, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

or if you are not looking always for the first word:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D:D)), D:E, 2, 0)))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, 
 "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, Intent!A2:A)&"\b"), Intent!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: the cell where your formula is is tab "Full List" cell B2

Comment: @MegaMikeJr try 2nd formula... `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Intent!A2:A)), Intent!A2:B, 2, 0)))` see your sheet

Comment: I'm still seeing words in column A of the "Full List" tab that don't meet the intent criteria. For Example, row 2 has text in column A "information systems" but the modifier isn't present in that text. So it wouldn't have a Intent category assigned to it. It would be blank. Is it possible to build the formula to look for the EXACT modifier within the text and then assign it a category?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, Intent!A2:A)&"\b"), Intent!A2:B, 2, 0)))`